# Redshift Unload Command having delimiter/Special Characters in Data String

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to unload data from Redshift to S3 in csv. This csv data is then converted to json message with required paramters.
It works good with normal data columns but when the data columns contain delimiter or special characters then the mapping is incorrect for generated csv file.
I am using '|' delimeter in unload command and if the '|' delimiter comes in any of the data string then it messes up the csv.
For example if the data is:

**INSERT INTO my_schema.my_table (atr_id, atr_dt, atr_name, atr_array_name, atr_array_float, atr_array_bool) VALUES('2987', '2015-06-28 05:07:00.000', 'name', '["|name1", "name2"]', '[1.2, 1.3]', '[true, false]');**

Unload Command:

**unload('select * from my_schema.my_table')
to 's3://my-bucket/filename'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::888555888:role/my-bucket-role' DELIMITER AS '|' addquotes escape HEADER ALLOWOVERWRITE parallel off;**

Then csv generated:

**atr_array_boolean|atr_array_float|atr_array_name|atr_dt|atr_id
[true, false]|[1.2, 1.3]|["|name1", "name2"]|2015-06-28 05:07:00|1987**

How do I add more special Characters to escape viz.{},[],delimiters, etc.?
So that once i am processing this CSV i will get the exact data which was there in columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are running into the difference between generic character separated files (TSV, PSV, or simple comma separated values)  and specified CSV - see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

When people have commas in their data the easiest thing to do is change the separator character to something that isn't in the data but this doesn't have a specified escaping process.  If you want to go this route you could change your separator to something not in your data like the ascii bell character.  Then whatever reads the file will need to work with this separator.

The other route to go is to use the Redshift unload capabilities to match the CSV spec.  You will want "Format CSV add quotes escape" but don't change the delimiter because the escape parameter doesn't know to escape any random delimiter you choose.  I think this is where you are running into issue - the | in the data is seen as a delimiter.

Now to be complete I believe Redshift will escape double quotes as " not "" as the spec states but most tools will work with either.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Bill for your approach. But I managed to use only "ESCAPE" keyword in unload command and then further did transformations to generated csv in order to get desired results.